# Android Google Play Application search issue

Tags: android, google-play

Hi I've recently placed my application on Google Play however I can not find it by searching the phrase
'golf scorecard free'

For example the app name is 'golf scorecard free' however I can find it when I search 'golfscorecardfree'.

What have I done wrong?

I did copy the project and rename so it's possible something might have not changed.

Is it the application name which determines what is searched in Google Play?

Any info would be great as I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I put "golfscorecardfree" your app is on #3! If I put "golf scorecard free" it is on #3 as well, I cant see your problem :)

Comment: Mine has a golf ball for the icon not the scorecard. When I search 'golfscorecardfree' mine is #5 when I search 'golf scorecard free' I can't find it :/. So no-one will ever find mine unless they search 'golfscorecardfree'

Comment: Could you provide a link to your app? I cannot find it at all, as it seems. My #5 has no golf ball icaon...

Comment: I couldnt find it, because its not availabe in my country. So  I see your app is very new, so its really important that the first users give good ratings in order to increase its score. check http://developer.android.com/distribute/index.html on how to distribute app and get good ratings. Ratings and the app name are the most important factor when it comes to search rankings

Answer (score 0):

After some research it turns out you shouldn't name your application the same as already published applications. This is understandable for copyright however the only reason I was trying this was to gain more exposure by calling my application name what Google Play auto suggested. This would get more attention than a custom name that no-one would search for. This is especially true when the search term is generic such as golf scorecard. I've renamed my app and it is found in the search.